# Angular2 [(ngModel)] numeric inputs are passed as string values to TypeScript's numeric properties

Tags: typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am testing a simple calculator which should sum 2 numbers but it concatanates them although I declare properties with type definitions.

It's OK if I code as `+this.number1 + +this.number2`. But isn't there any way to pass them from `[(ngModel)]` to typescript class as numeric values?

I have researched but cannot find anything. Am I missing something?

**app.component.html**

```
`...
<TextField hint="Number 1" [(ngModel)]="number1" keyboardType="number"></TextField>
<TextField hint="Number 2" [(ngModel)]="number2" keyboardType="number"></TextField>
<Button text="Calculate" (tap)="calculate()"></Button>
...`
```

**app.component.ts**

```
...
public number1: number = 0;
public number2: number = 0;
public result: number = 0;

calculate(){
        this.result = this.number1 + this.number2;
        // if I code this as "this.result = +this.number1 + +this.number2;" it is working.
}
...
```

Comment: Labeling something `:number` is a compile time check only and when it's transpiled JS is gonna do what JS is gonna do (which is be loosely typed). There are pluses (expressive!) and minuses (unexpected concatenation!) to this.

Comment: silentsod, thanks for the answer. Yes absolutely. But I just wonder isn't there anything to succeed that in transpiling operation.

Comment: @silentsod Angular could give a chance us to set data type like `<TextField dataType="numeric"...` :)